# Fixed footer via CSS only

Tags: css

I want to make the class .cart to be fixed at the bottom the the screen at all times like a fixed footer. Currently user has to scroll all the way to the bottom of the page to view this div. I have tried the following css but to now avail.

Although this code works fine for my in JS fiddle but not on my webpage (link below)

JS Fiddle -- > http://jsfiddle.net/Lec5yu1d/2/

My webpage -- > http://omgjewelz.com/create-your-set

```
.cart { position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;  }
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/demo doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: The example above will result in the element `.cart` being display at the bottom edge of the screen. Are you sure, that there it not some other CSS that overrides those styles? The JSFiddle you added shows exactly that.

Comment: Be aware though, that **not all mobile browsers support fixed positioning**. See also [Brad frost: fixed positioning in mobile browsers](http://bradfrost.com/blog/mobile/fixed-position/).

Comment: @feeela None that i know of. That is what i need help with locating the source of the problem.

Comment: @Paulie_D i have updated my question with JS fiddle. Thanks your input.

Comment: Code **in the question** - not a fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi adding this code to your style will make it work, 
You need to make footer sticky along with positioning it, So here I added bottom:0px for you.

```
footer.site-footer {
    position: sticky;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

For better view, I will suggest you to use background white behind the text div, as right now its transparent so it will mess up with content,

```
.footer-bottom {
    background: white;
}
```

Comment: I dont want to make that sticky. Actually i wan to make the element .cart stick it i the one shown in yellow color in the screenshot here : https://imgur.com/a/HrQyCtM

Comment: Here you go : 
`.form-element.form-element-field5.form-element-2.form-element-type-customText.is-required-false.odd.-handle.default-false.options-false.index-false {
    position: sticky;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 100px;
    z-index: 110;
}`

don't forgot to give it some ID or Class, so you have easy css selector.
if that solves you can upvote it ;)

Comment: Thanks for your input ! Its working on desktop only ... is there a way to make it work on mobile too ?  If you resize the window you can see it stops being sticky once the screen gets smaller.

Comment: you just need to apply position: sticky!important; because this style on mobile is getting overridden. 
It will work fine, once you apply important on position and bottom.

Comment: tired that still not working on mobile. Also it has even stopped working on desktop too. Is it working on mobile on your end ?

Comment: Yes its working fine on my end.

Comment: Can you please check the webpage again. Code has completely stopped working

Comment: I tired this code its simpler and its working fine on desktop. But still not on mobile. My new code is   .form-element-7 { position: sticky !important; bottom: 0 !important ; left: 100px !important ; z-index: 110 !important; padding-left: 80px !important; }

Comment: Make sure you are adding it to right selector, .form-element-7 is not the right selector, there are multiple classes, for me with this selector it worked : 
.form-element.form-element-field5.form-element-2.form-element-type-customText.is-required-false.odd.-handle.default-false.options-false.index-false

I will recommend you to use ID there to target it.